# Интеграция товаров в Лиды битрикс24

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Всем привет. Есть сайт, на котором клиент покупает товар, он записывается в БД, и отправляется на почту. Появилась необходимость автоматизировать процесс с помощью битрикс24. Задача, нужно что бы добавлялись заявка в лиды после того был процесс оформления заявки с сайта. Был найден [пример работы с лидами](https://gettotop.ru/crm/bitrix24-lidy-s-sajta-avtomaticheskoe-sozdanie-lidov/) и все нормально работает. Лиды добавляется все хорошо. Но, я не могу в лиды добавить товары которые пришли? как это сделать? т.е. простые данные в виде наименованные форма, телефон, имя, все работает, а вот какие товары купили? Конечно есть вариант сделать это все в примечании, но хочется использовать по максимум возможность битрикса.

Comment: Добавьте в Битрикс24 товары и при создании лида перехватывайте, проверяйте и записывайте.

Answer (score 0):

Ни как. В приведенной вами статье слишком занудный скрипт: сокеты, 443 порт, POST Запрос, Curl не хватает, а по факту для создания лида достаточно выполнить get запрос, т.е. весь скрипт это одна строка внутри file_get_contents.

Данный запрос существует только для того чтобы лейдинг-пейдж за 1 минуту подключать лиды к Битрикс24.

Но на этом все, нету других подобных запросов в Битрикс24.
Хотите добавлять товары и заказы:
- изучайте api Битрикс и api Битрикс24.
- интегрируйте стандартным модулем магазина Битрикс, для редакции Малый бизнес.